# Почему не проходит POST запрос, хотя GET отправляеться(Laravel+https)?

Tags: laravel, https

Есть Laravel, установленый на виртуальном хостинге с ssl. Через https://hurl.it/ я отправляю GET запрос - проходит. Когда отправляю POST - 500 Internal Server Error.
Логи ларавел чистые. Логи сервера посмотреть увы не могу, виртуальный хостинг же(. В раутах тоже всё нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что нужно с запросом отправлять токен.
Пример отправки POST ajax'ом:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

$.ajax({
    url: '/home/upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Если тебе нужно в обычной форме отправить то сделай hidden инпут с именем _token и в value подставь токен.

Comment: чуть не забыл, не забудь создать роут для post

Comment: роут есть, но фишка вот в чём, я данные должен получать от телеграма. И раз такое дело то почему ошибка генерируеться сервером? Ведь если токен не соответствует тому что на сервере(либо его нет) то ошибка должна генерироваться на уровне фреймворка?

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: и да, я не отправлял форму, мне необходимо принять пост запрос от телеграма), поэтому я в сервис провайдере отвечающему за роботу с токенами добавил в исключения раут для приёма пост данных

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки, что проблема с токеном, можно маршруты выключить в

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
    'http://example.com/foo/bar',
    'http://example.com/foo/*',
];
}
```